# Index out of Bounds error at beginning of second iteration

Tags: c#, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

When running through a loop, my loop processes through the first iteration without errors, then fails with an Index out of Bounds error. Walking through the code, I'm not able to see why it's throwing this exception.

I also changed the loop iterations to `i < 1`, which allowed the program to run. When I changed the iterations to `i < 2`, I received the exception error again.

The code I have does this:

```
    private void build()
    {
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Clear();
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new InHouse(1, "Part 1", 5.0, 5, 15, 3, 25));
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new InHouse(2, "Part 2", 10.0, 10, 25, 5, 2));
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new Outsourced(3, "Part 3", 15.0, 12, 20, 7, "Acme"));
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new Outsourced(4, "Wheel", 12.0, 15, 30, 10, "Carpathia"));
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new Outsourced(5, "Pedal", 8.0, 24, 50, 22, "BendORama"));
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new Outsourced(6, "Chain", 9.0, 12, 15, 3, "Michael's Metals"));
      AllPartsList.PartsList.Add(new InHouse(7, "Seat", 4.0, 8, 10, 2, 15));
    }

    private void display()
    {
      PartTable.Rows.Clear();
      PartTable.Refresh();
      for (int i = 0; i < AllPartsList.PartsList.Count; i++)
      {
        PartTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = AllPartsList.PartsList[i].PartID;
        PartTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = AllPartsList.PartsList[i].PartName;
        PartTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = AllPartsList.PartsList[i].price;
        PartTable.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = AllPartsList.PartsList[i].inStock;
      }
    }
```

AllPartsList class:

```
    class AllPartsList
    {
      private static BindingList<Part> partsList = new BindingList<Part>();
      public static BindingList<Part> PartsList { get { return partsList; } set { partsList = value; } }

      public static string CurrentPart { get; set; }
      public static int CurrentPartID { get; set; }
      public static int CurrentPartIndex { get; set; }
      public static double CurrentPartPrice { get; set; }
      public static int CurrentPartInventory { get; set; }

      public static Part lookupPart(int i)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < PartsList.Count; j++)
        {
          if (PartsList[j].PartID.Equals(i))
          {
            CurrentPartIndex = j;
            return PartsList[j];
          }
        }
        CurrentPartIndex = -1;
        return null;
      }

      internal static void swap(Part prt)
      {
        PartsList.Insert(CurrentPartIndex, prt);
        PartsList.RemoveAt(CurrentPartIndex + 1);
      }
    }
```

From what is programmed, I would expect the loop to run through 7 iterations, then load the information to the DataGridView when I run the program.

Comment: did you check if your PartTable contains enough Rows to cater your AllPartsList iteration?

Comment: Can't you use your `AllPartsList.PartsList` as the DataSource of the DGV?

Comment: When you examined `PartTable.Rows` and `AllPartsList.PartsList` in the debugger what did you find?

Comment: @SKLTFZ: PartTable is the DGV.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp: I don't think this is the same... I know WHAT the error is, I just don't understand why I'm getting it, as nothing in the code indicates that I should be getting it.

Comment: @Jimi: Added the `AllPartsList.PartsList` class to the question.

Comment: @JasonRapp try to remove 4 lines of code about PartTable within your loop and see if the error persisted. if there is no error, then it means the issue is about your DGV instead of the iteration of AllPartsList

Comment: This is a complete lack of debugging, you haven't even worked out which index is out of range, and just leaving us to guess. Step through with the debugger and give us more information

Comment: @TheGeneral: I did step through with the debugger. The value that comes as out of bounds is when `i = 1`, and is out of bounds on the left side of the assignment operator for the first statement in the loop: `PartTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = AllPartsList.PartsList[i].PartID;`. As I said, it works for the first iteration, then fails with the out of bounds error.

Comment: This is not what i asked, there are 3 indexers there, which one is it, which one is causing the exception, is it `Rows[i]` is it  `Cells[0]` or is it `PartsList[i]`

Comment: Did you miss adding new DGV row, before you allocating the data to columns. you might consider creating the new DGV row inside for loop.

Comment: You are calling `PartTable.Rows.Clear();` and then in the loop, trying to access `PartTable.Rows[i]`.  Since there are no rows in the DGV (because you just cleared them), it throws the exception.  Perhaps just before the `for` loop, you should call `PartTable.Rows.Add(AllPartsList.PartsList.Count);` to make sure there are enough rows in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Dunaway and Srikanth were correct: I wasn't adding any rows, because I had been staring at the code for hours at that point, and was just not thinking. Thanks for the help!